# MySQL EXPLAIN shows key not being used. Is it doing anything at all?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing, explain

Let's say I have three tables: **shipments**, **customers** and **stores**. The **shipments** table has two indexes: *customer_id* of type INT (references the customers table), and *date* of type datetime. The **customers** table has one index: *store_id* of type INT (references the store table).

If I filter shipments by date, I see the *date* index being used:

```
EXPLAIN extended SELECT * FROM shipments
WHERE date >= '2020-04-01' AND date <= '2020-05-01';

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipments | range | date          | date | 9       | NULL  | 250796 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+------------------------+
```

However, the output for these next two queries confuses me, because it is pretty much the same:

```
EXPLAIN extended SELECT shipments.* FROM shipments
LEFT JOIN customers ON shipments.customer_id = customers.id
WHERE customers.store_id = 100 AND 
shipments.date >= '2020-04-01 00:0:00.0' AND shipments.date <= '2020-05-01 00:0:00.0';

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys     | key         | key_len | ref           | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customers | ref   | PRIMARY, store_id | store_id    | 5       | const         | 38     |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipments | ref   | customer_id, date | customer_id | 5       | customers.id  | 663    |   100.00 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------------------+

EXPLAIN extended SELECT shipments.* FROM shipments
LEFT JOIN customers ON shipments.customer_id = customers.id
WHERE customers.store_id = 100;

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys     | key         | key_len | ref           | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customers | ref   | PRIMARY, store_id | store_id    | 5       | const         | 38     |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | shipments | ref   | customer_id       | customer_id | 5       | customers.id  | 663    |   100.00 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------------------------+
```

**Question nº1**: Does this output mean that the first of those two queries doesn't use the *date* index at all? I have read that MySQL won't use more than one index per table, so is my *date* index making any difference at all in terms of performance? (in my program, all queries that filter by date range look pretty much like that one) Assuming that there are tons of customers and tons of shipments and tons of queries like this being launched at the same time, how should I go about improving performance?

**Question nº2**: Why is the value of 'rows' in the output the same for those two queries, if the first one implies more filtering than the first one? Shouldn't it be different? Obviously I don't understand this properly, so can someone please explain it to me?

Thanks in advance!

Note: This is mysql 5.5.56 and the tables are InnoDB.

Comment: For the first of your two queries, where your `WHERE` clause includes `shipments.date >= '2020-04-01 00:0:00.0' AND shipments.date <= '2020-05-01 00:0:00.0'`, the `possible_keys` shows `customer_id, date`. What makes you think the `date` index isn't being used at all for that query?

Comment: It was my understanding that the index actually being used is the one under 'key', and that MySQL won't use more than one index per table except in some situations (section 8.2.1.3 in the manual) which do not seem to be the case with this query. Is it not like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a `LEFT` join since you are requiring `store_id = 100`.  That won't change the performance; the Optimizer already figured it out.  (It does help with readers trying to figure out the intent of the query.)

You say `SELECT *`.  If you don't need all the columns, don't ask for all of them.  If any is a big `TEXT` column, the text is sitting in an "off-record" block, which takes effort to fetch.

`INDEX(customer_id), INDEX(date)` is not as good as the "composite" `INDEX(customer_id, date)`  With this, it can focus on the entries for that one customer, and scan across the dates desired.  This is likely to make a speed improvement.  Note:  the order of the columns in that index is important -- put the `=` column(s) (`customer_id`) first, the range (`date >=...`) last.

(Q1) MySQL does not (with rare exceptions) use more than one index at a time.  You are filtering `shipments` on two things:  `customer_id` and `date`, not just `date`.  This query, on the other hand, would use `INDEX(date)`, and would *not* use the composite index, above:  `SELECT * FROM shipments where date >= CURDATE();`  (That gets all information about all shipments so far today for all customers.

A side note:  You are including midnight at both ends.  Change the last comparison from `<=` to `<`.

(Q2) The numbers in `EXPLAIN` are estimates.  They are based on "statistics" and "probes" that are not necessarily very precise.  Also, some tips are ignored in some cases.  A blatant omission is `LIMIT`.

Beware using `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX`.  If you feel the need for such, you may be missing something important.  If you do use it, "it may help today, but make things worse tomorrow when the data distribution changes.

A tip:  For comparisons with a DATE / DATETIME / DATETIME(1) / TIMESTAMP, a time of midnight can leave off the 'time' part:  `'2020-05-01'` works the same as `'2020-05-01 00:0:00.0'`

Version 5.5?  That's pretty old.  5.6 adds `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`, which would provide more info -- details on index usage, sorting, query_cost, etc.

"This optimization stuff is still pretty obscure to me." -- Yes.  And MySQL has one of the simpler Optimizers.

Comment: Details like the use of `SELECT *` or including midnights at both ends, etc, were just because I was trying to simplify the real life case as much as possible and didn't pay much attention, but thanks anyway for those remarks. Also, it turns out that after doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` (which in fact did recreate + analyze, according to the response), now `EXPLAIN` says that the multiple index is being used, so I'll try to test how much the whole thing is improved, thanks.

Comment: @javier - Be careful; sometimes simplification leads to providing a _different_ query that elicits a _different_ answer.

Comment: I forgot to make a last question, sorry. After creating the composite index you suggested and running `EXPLAIN` on the query with the join and the data range, now MySQL is using the composite index, but in the column 'ref' I still see only 'customers.id' (same as in my original post), whereas I expected to also see 'const' because MySQL should be using a constant (the dates in the range) to compare them to the 'date' part of the composite index. Does the fact that I don't see 'const' in there mean that the 'date' part of the index is not being used? Or it means no such thing?

Comment: @javier - That is a deficiency in `EXPLAIN`.  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` might provide more assurances.  Or, measuring the "Handler" counts can give evidence that it is "doing the right thing":  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it filters by customers.store_id, an then does a join backwards to the shipments table based on customer_id.

You may be able to improve on that by replacing the index on shipments(customer_id) with shipments(customer_id, date), unless that index already covers both fields.

2) Because it is an estimate based on the index statistics, mainly cardinality of each index.

Comment: I had thought about an index like `shipments(customer_id, date)`, but once I added it the optimizer wouldn't use it, and in fact if I force it by writing `USE INDEX (customer_id_and_date)`, the value of 'rows' in `EXPLAIN` gets much bigger.  Afterwards I executed it both ways (with and without using that new index) with `SQL_NO_CACHE`, and after some tests with  the execution times seem pretty similar. In fact, If I do `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'last_query_cost'`, the value for the query with the new index is 100 times greater. This optimization stuff is still pretty obscure to me... :)

Comment: @javier - The failure of that composite index is strange; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be a clue there.

Comment: @RickJames Just fo follow up on this thread as well: after doing optimize table, MySQL started using the composite index